# Issues launching Juypter Lab

Tags: python, macos, anaconda, jupyter, macos-catalina

I used to be able to launch jupyter lab from my command line. Since I've updated to Mac OS Catalina, I am not able to do this anymore. I've tried moving the files to the users folder as well as reinstalling anaconda.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/jupyter", line 10, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jupyter_core/command.py", line 247, in main
    command = _jupyter_abspath(subcommand)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jupyter_core/command.py", line 134, in _jupyter_abspath
    'Jupyter command `{}` not found.'.format(jupyter_subcommand)
Exception: Jupyter command `jupyter-lab` not found.
```

Comment: is it not 'jupyter lab' the right command?

Comment: i used that and got that specific error

Answer (score 0):

I would just go to the file where the error came from and change where it tries to execute `jupyter-lab` to `jupyter lab`. Probably doesn't work, but I've done this kind of stuff to fix some incompatibility issues so I'll just put this out here :)